# Choosing the photo size in tumblr API

Tags: php, xml, api, tumblr

I want to include the latest post from a tumblr blog in my website, which works fine. I can't figure out how to choose a specific tag from the API, though.

The XML has the following structure:

```
<tumblr>
    <posts>
        <post>
            <photo-url max-width="500">
                image_500.jpg
            </photo-url>
            <photo-url max-width="250">
                image_250.jpg
            </photo-url>
        </post>
    </posts>
</tumblr>
```

Now how can I specify that I want the 250 version in the third line here?

```
<?php
    $xmlResult = file_get_contents($tumblr_url_aktuell);
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($tumblr_url_aktuell);
    $image = $xml->posts->post->{'photo-url'}
?>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to loop through them to select the one you want.

```
<?php
    $xmlResult = file_get_contents($tumblr_url_aktuell);
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($tumblr_url_aktuell);
    foreach($xml->posts->post->{'photo-url'} as $photoURL){
        if((string)$photoURL['max-width'] == '250'){
            $image = $photoURL;
        }
    }
?>
```

[See reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php#example-5069)